# How is a Pandas crosstab different from a Pandas pivot_table?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Both pandas' `crosstab` and `pivot_table` functions seem to provide the exact same functionality. Are there any differences?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73060100/19123103). It’s a long one but it’s Section 1 covers `crosstab` vs `pivot_table`. Both are applications of `groupby`.

Answer (score 51):

The main difference between the two is the `pivot_table` expects your input data to already be a DataFrame; you pass a DataFrame to `pivot_table` and specify the `index`/`columns`/`values` by passing the column names as strings.  With `cross_tab`, you  don't necessarily need to have a DataFrame going in, as you just pass array-like objects for `index`/`columns`/`values`.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b5dd6a38b18b3da8736a64ce3ce9b80bbe44f35f/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L344-L470) for `crosstab`, it essentially takes the array-like objects you pass, creates a DataFrame, then calls `pivot_table` as appropriate.

In general, use `pivot_table` if you already have a DataFrame, so you don't have the additional overhead of creating the same DataFrame again.  If you're starting from array-like objects and are only concerned with the pivoted data, use `crosstab`.  In most cases, I don't think it will really make a difference which function you decide to use.

Comment: I timed a few options, and turns out pivot_table is one order of magnitude slower than crosstab, and even that is slower than a simple but clunky groupby approach, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503717/alternative-to-groupby-for-generating-a-summary-table-from-tidy-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Mpa this makes no sense. crosstab calls pivot_table, how is crosstab going to be faster? crosstab adds overhead. This article shows crosstab is the slowest between groupby, pivot_table and crosstab https://ramiro.org/notebook/pandas-crosstab-groupby-pivot/

Answer (score 26):

Is it the same, if in [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) use `aggfunc=len` and `fill_value=0`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Col X'], df['Col Y'])
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Col X'], columns=['Col Y'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

EDIT: There is more difference:

Default `aggfunc` are different: [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) - `np.mean`, [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) - `len`.

Parameter `margins_name` is only in `pivot_table`.

In `pivot_table` you can use `Grouper` for `index` and `columns` keywords.

---

I think if you need simply frequency table, `crosstab` function is better.

Comment: But it seems you can also have a `aggfunc` for the crosstab function.

Comment: pivot_table has a bit more 'analytical' flexibility, such as filling NA values, adding subtotals, etc., but absolutely at the cost of more overhead, as mentioned above.

Comment: regarding overhead it is just the other way round (if there is any performance difference at all), as `crosstab` first creates a dataframe and then [calls `pivot_table`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.0/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L570).

Answer (score 11):

The `pivot_table` does not have the `normalize` argument, unfortunately.

In `crosstab`, the `normalize` argument calculates percentages by dividing each cell by the sum of cells, as described below:

- `normalize = 'index'` divides each cell by the sum of its row
- `normalize = 'columns'` divides each cell by the sum of its column
- `normalize = True` divides each cell by the total of all cells in the table

Comment: For me this seems the most notorius difference. I think it is very strange that this functionality is not included in `pivot_table`.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot table shows the values from data.
Crosstab represent frequency of the data .

Comment: Please provide some example to explain your answer using `crosstab` and `pivot_table`. That way, the your answer will be much clearer.

Comment: You can do multiple types of aggregation with crosstabs not just counts by specifying the aggfunc argument.

Answer (score 1):

Crosstab utilized count() aggregation to fill the values while pivot_table would use any other aggregation such as sum().