# pandas how to create simple cross-tab without aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, crosstab

I have a pandas table with 3 columns: parent_male, parent_female, offsprings - all strings.
I want to create a simple sparse crosstab table of male vs female and the offsprings as the values - how can I write an aggfunc that do so. (no real aggregation is needed) - just put an empty string in the blanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='parent_male', columns='parent_female', values='offsprings')
```

If get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

So final solution is:

```
ct = pd.pivot_table(d['male'], d['female'], d['offsprings'], aggfunc=','.join)
```

Comment: thanks - I had a problem with the values as strings, since the index contains duplicate entries. I found the solution below...

Comment: if have there problem you can use `aggfunc=','.join` ;)

Comment: final solution, that works well thanks to you guys:

ct = pd.crosstab(hyb['male'], hyb['female'], hyb['line'], aggfunc=','.join)

Comment: There is interesting [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36267745/2901002) about `crosstab` vs `pivot_table`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here...
[Pandas Groupby Agg Function Does Not Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439023/pandas-groupby-agg-function-does-not-reduce)
and I used the info. from the comments above...

```
ct = pd.crosstab(d['male'], d['female'], d['offsprings'], aggfunc=','.join)
```